# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a web application and I have been facing this issue for a while after looking at multiple post I still was unable to solve this issue. I'm using tomcat 7.0.23 which provides el-api which i believe is the jar thought to be missing. I have not included any jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder at all I am adding all of my dependencies through pom.xml because of maven. I have attempted all of the possible quick fixes i could think of including maven clean/install server clean(multiple times), project clean, adding tomcat to the targeted runtimes. in my build path is tomcat, jdk1.6, and maven)

The pom.xml and web.xml files that I am using are identical my other team members and they are currently working so i don't believe the issue is there.

Here is the error I am getting when starting the server

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:403)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initStartupFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:376)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 13 more
```

these are the dependices after a maven clean/ install

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
captcha-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
cmu_time_awb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
cmu_us_kal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
cmudict04-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
cmulex-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
cmutimelex-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
cxf-api-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-core-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.7.0.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
en_us-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
freemarker-2.3.9.jar    
freetts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
freetts-jsapi10-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
jcaptcha-1.0-mod-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
jdom-1.1.jar
jettison-1.0.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.6.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jtds-1.2.4.jar
junit-4.7.jar
jxl-2.6.12.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
mail-1.4.5.jar
myfaces-api-2.1.0.jar
myfaces-impl-2.1.0.jar
neethi-3.0.2.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
primefaces-3.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-tiger-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-ldif-batch-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-ldif-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-odm-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
tomahawk-1.1.6.jar
velocity-1.6.2.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.3.jar
```

Comment: Would you please show your code and line number of exception?

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` is often thrown when a class is found in classpath but its loading fail. Could you please add the dependecies found in `WEB-INF/lib` after a `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: @MasudCSECUET what code would you like to see i am getting this when starting the server. the code isn't the issue the project is working in other team members local environment. my logs aren't printing with line numbers but the second line from the top seems to be the issue

Comment: Add -verbose:class in your tomcat server and other team members' server to see which jar is loaded to load the class. This could help in determining whether you have the same setup as others

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont I have edited the post with the list of dependencies. thank you

Comment: Well, I don't see any problem in your dependencies. If everything is ok for your colleagues, you may try replace ${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/el-api.jar in your tomcat installation with the same from a colleague.

Answer (score 3):

The “javax.el.ExpressionFactory” class belongs to the “el-api.jar” library, you can download it from Maven central repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and place it in tomcat/lib directory.

[Alternative Solution](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-el-expressionfactory/)